# Where can I find a good Sextante Modeller tutorial?

Tags: sextante, references

I'd like to enrich my knowledge of the Sextante Modeller. Do you have any good suggestion of a book/workshop etc. to dig into the modeller?

Comment: There are a few Youtube videos for the Sextante modeler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find the best, most complete documentation on the QGIS documentation pages: http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/processing/index.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know, if I can download that piece of documentation somowhere?

Comment: I think the documentation team is still working on the PDF export.